# How to store password field in oracle 11g database in encrypted form?

Tags: oracle, encryption, oracle11g, passwords, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table in database with this structure:

Username 
Password
Age 
email
Address
Phone Number

I want to store this table's data manually(not by an input from a program) in the data base so that i can fetch it later for further use.

I want to store the password in the database in the encrypted form so that nobody can see the password.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Don't store passwords. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go to the following site and check it out:-

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10746/asotrans.htm

You can use Master Encryption Key.It is implemented in a lot of places where user details should not be misused such as credit card no.